# Azure cloud shell not switching subscription

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

When I run this command on azure cloudshell, it shows the subscription is switched but it actually is not. Because the next command I execute is done in another subscription(initial one).

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId <id> -verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Select-AzSubscription` is alias of `Set-AzContext` cmdlet
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10848

Microsoft recommends to use

```
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName 'MySubscriptionName' | Set-AzContext -Name 'MyContextName'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/azure/manage-subscriptions-azureps?view=azps-5.3.0